# How to send JWT token in flutter in a request header?

Tags: flutter, rest, http, request, jwt

I'm trying to send a request to a server that requires a parameter called 'fid' sent in the header for autherization.

Here's what you can help me with.

Payload to be sent in the header

```
{ "fid" : "Some alphaNum value", "type": "some type string" }
```

I would like to know how to use jwt encoding in flutter and how to use that in the header of a request to encode and send this payload across to the server for autherization. I'm planning to use HS256 algo for encoding. Since I'm new to the concept of Jwt, there might be errors in the way I asked this question. Please share your thoughts. I would also like to know how to use the secret key too -- like how to generate the key, and where in the request to send this.

Request

```
fetchData({required String type, required String fid, String url}) async{

 <How to get the json web token>

 http.get(url, header : <What do I send here>);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use http or Dio package for calling API requests in flutter,
you can set headers as follows,

- https://pub.dev/packages/dio
- https://pub.dev/packages/http

```
final response = http.get(url,
        headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token"});
```